# Android SDK Manager - cant delete 4.4W (API20) package

Tags: sdk, android-studio

I'm having trouble to preview EditText, I've understand that it happened due to recently update of 4.4W (API20) package.

But, when I try to delete this package from SDK Manager, it show me the deleting message and nothing happened, it not give me any error or any other message, just "stand out there".

Answer (score 17):

1. Go to your SDK installation folder.
2. Right click on SDK Manager.
3. Choose Run as Administrator.
4. Select whatever you want to delete.

and you're done.